# How can I add a reference to PresentationCore in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, .net-5

How can I add a reference to `PresentationCore` to an existing .NET 5 class library?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `TargetFramework` and `UseWPF`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! ... Researching your answer I also found the following hint: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#available-sdks

Comment: Note that since .NET 5 you don't need to set `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` (as it was necessary for older .NET Core versions). `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` is sufficient.

Comment: The "-windows" prefix is absolutely necessary. Setting UseWPF to true without specifying the target framework OS is not enough (net5.0 or 6.0, which is the default value, will not do).

Comment: @Thern  You mean the `-windows` suffix in the `<TargetFramework>`? That's of course necessary, as shown in the answer, because WPF only runs on Windows. Not sure what you are trying say.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to emphasize this, as I stumbled upon this solution, added <UseWPF>true<UseWPF>, and it still didn't work. Only afterwards I saw that my target framework value was net6.0, not net6.0-windows. That's why I put some emphasis on this because someone else might overlook this as I did.